# Change table size and place on orientation

Tags: ios, uitableview, orientation-changes

I want to create one table programmatically and change it depending on changes orientation. the problem is that, when i start the app the table always appears in the same location no matter how is orientated.

and i dont understad why the method updateViewOnRotate is called 3 times for the first time.

the code is all in one class, UIViewController.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
 addObserver:self 
 selector:@selector(updateViewOnRotate:)
 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification 
 object:nil];
[super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void) updateViewOnRotate:(NSNotification *)notification {
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];  

if ((orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {  
    // present the other viewController, it's only viewable in landscape  
    [[self.view subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    // get rid of the landscape controller  
    UIView *opcionesView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 250, self.view.frame.size.height)] autorelease];
    opcionesView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
    UITableView *table = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 250, 500) style:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease];

    [opcionesView addSubview:table];
    [self.view addSubview:opcionesView];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];      
}  
else{  

    [[self.view subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

    UIView *opcionesView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, self.view.frame.size.height)] autorelease];
    opcionesView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
    UITableView *table = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 250, 500) style:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease];

    [opcionesView addSubview:table];
    //      UINavigationBar *b=[[[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 50)]autorelease];
    //      [opcionesView addSubview:b];

    [self.view addSubview:opcionesView];

}  

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't post comments yet.  If I could, this'd be one.

Why aren't you using the - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation or other view controller callbacks to do this?  Maybe it would work better.

Comment: i have that method returning YES and it does change orientation of the view but i want to put the table in one place depending of the orientation.

Comment: tarmes pointed to - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation: but you return YES in -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: wich is not the same. Also you may be interested in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: and didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:  Anyway, you should take a look at ViewController programming guide